# db schema for a object with multiple foreign key tables

Tags: schema

I have a question table which contains `question_id`, `question_text` and `choice_type_id` ( say freetext, binary choice and multiple choices )

Now, the question table (which has `question_id, question_text, choice_type_id`) has a foreign key to the choice type table ( `choice_type_id, choice_type_desc`) . Now all the different choice types have a different schema.

For *multiple choice*,  I want to store multiple choice fields against a question. For *binary choice* , I want to store two choices against a question and for *freetext*, I have no choices.

How do I populate a question's choices based on its type and model this in a sql like db. I would further want to see user interactions with each of these questions and choices within that question ( i.e. the user chose which choices or entered what text for the given question)

I can model the `question_choice` table as a big table which can have all the three types and based on the type certain columns can have values and all other remain null.

This would be a very sparse representation and I'm not sure how this will scale.

What would be the best schema design considering I want fast reads and the question types will keep increasing further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply include in your model a choice table for each type of choice that your 
Your field `choice_type_id` is essentially a kind of **partitioning attribute**.  It indicates what type of child table is applicable.

So far you have three tables: `MULTIPLE_CHOICE`, `BINARY_CHOICE`, and `FREE_TEXT` (although you might consider binary choice to be a special case of multiple choice).

Each of these tables is a child of your `QUESTION` table, i.e. they all have a `question_id` foreign key.  The multiple choice table will have multiple records pointing to `QUESTION` whereas the other tables will have one - depending on how you model binary choices.

Note that this physical arrangement could be flattened out using a view to look like the one big table with sparse columns that you want to avoid.  The one big flat (sparse) table might be handy for reporting, but since you're worried about scale you might want to avoid a sparse table for physical storage.

Your user answer tables would be children of the various choice tables that intersect the `USER` and the appropriate choice, since each question is answered by multiple users.

For more about this approach, see my answers to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/db-design-for-a-quiz-with-variable-number-of-answer-choices-and-each-worth-diff/24019#24019) and [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16002/survey-database-design-associate-an-answer-to-a-user/16010#16010) here on DBA.SE.